# CentOS 7 sudo not running commands as user

Tags: linux, centos, bash, postgresql

Im having a bit of an issue im hoping someone can help me with.

Im writing a bash script to set up some software, i.e nginx, postgres etc

Everything is going well so far except for when i get to setting up PostgreSQL

I need to run the following command;

```
psql -c "CREATE ROLE myboxname LOGIN UNENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'secret' SUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;"
```

BUT i need to do it through sudo.

My full command is as follows;

```
sudo su - postgres psql -c "CREATE ROLE myboxname LOGIN UNENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'secret' SUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;"
```

When i run this, i get the following;

```
psql: CREATE: command not found
```

But if i do the following it works fine

```
sudo su - postgres
psql -c "CREATE ROLE myboxname LOGIN UNENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'secret' SUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;"
```

Am i missing a flag in my sudo command or something? .... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If user is root, you can use **-c** option with **su**

```
su - postgres -c "<commands>"
```

Or use **sudo** with **-c**

```
sudo -U postgres -c "<commands>" -s /bin/bash
```

Comment: Don't use `sudo su`, as `sudo` can do the job. If you are `root` user you also can use `su  - postgres ...` but there is no need to use both in conjunction.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the warning. I updated the answer.